# Azure Remote App: Import Excel Range Into Access

Tags: azure

I have the following code within a form startup procedure in an Access Front End accessing an SQL Back End. The code below, which simply opens an excel file, goes to the data tab and retrieves the value from a named range, works fine. However, when I migrate the front end to Azure Image and Publish in Remote Desktop, while the value is retrieved and updated to the database, the procedure hangs up. Using Alt-Ctl-End to open Task Manager, I find Excel still open, and need to End Task on Excel before my Access front end moves forward in the procedure. My hunch, Excel is waiting for a response on something, but there are no dialogs open to deal with. Any ideas?

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlbook = xl.workbooks.Open(sRWFile)
Set xlsheet = xlbook.worksheets("Data")
xl.Visible = False
xlbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
With xlsheet
dValue = .Range(sRWRange)
End With
xlbook.Close , True
Set xlsheet = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
```

Comment: did you try adding excel to the published apps?

Comment: Yes, excel is published. The app uses excel in various places through function calls without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlbook = xl.workbooks.Open(sRWFile)
Set xlsheet = xlbook.worksheets("Data")
xl.Visible = False
xlbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
With xlsheet
dValue = .Range(sRWRange)
End With
xlbook.Close , True
**xl.quit**
Set xlsheet = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
```